# firefox send ajax request before submit the form

Tags: ajax, firefox, onsubmit

I put a `onsubmit="return before_submit();` in my form, an ajax request lies in `before_submit` funciton, `onsubmit` and `ajax` both work well on Chrome, but it seems that FireFox jump the ajax request and go to submit the form directly. So the server can't receive ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if ajax request completed, submit the form use javascript.

```
  $.post('url', 
    {'name': name, 'value': value, 'x': Math.random()}, function(ret, status) {
      if (status=='success'){
        $('#form').submit();
      } else {
        alert('Sorry! Abnormal network connection or server error')
      }
  });
```

This works on firefox well

Comment: Is there some documentation regarding this behavior from Firefox? Why is the ajax not allowed before normal form submission?